# error in your SQL syntax;check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax

Tags: sql-update, syntax-error, mariadb

I am trying to update values to the database using the query given below, but unfortunately the following error occurs. Help me with this !

Error: UPDATE internal_marks marks='11' WHERE sno='1';
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '='11' WHERE sno='1'' at line 1

```
$sql = "UPDATE internal_marks marks='".$one."' WHERE sno='1'";
```

The variable $one is the value that i get from a form. I want my table to be updated the value which i got from that form.

Comment: Please  use your favorite search engine for *SQL tutorial*. This is very basic SQL syntax.

Comment: What will happen if $one has a quote in it?  You _must_ escape things you put into SQL queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

missing SET

```
$sql = "UPDATE internal_marks 
      set  marks='".$one."' WHERE sno='1'";
```

anyway you shoudl take a look at you db driver for prepared  statement and binding param .. because the use of php var in sql is at risk for sql injection